# Set alert for when an item is deleted from a view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, list-view

I'm looking for a way to receive an alert for when an item is no longer shown in a specific view.
I have a view which filters items based on the value in the `Status` column. I need to keep track of this specific view to know how often items disappear from this view because their status switches to Completed. Is there a way to set up an alert for this, preferrably sending me a weekly report?

Apparently the standard alert functionality for *when an item is deleted* can only be used on the complete list, not a specific view (unlike *when an item changes*)

From the MS support site page on setting alerts:

> **Change Type:**    Choose to receive alerts for all changes, when new items are added, or existing items are modified or deleted. No alert is sent when an item is deleted from a view.

I know I can just create a workflow for this, but this seems a bit 'much'..

(Using SharePoint 2013 on prem)

Comment: But item is not DELETED from the view, he is only EXCLUDED based on the FILTER properties, there is NOT any event reciever for this... One thing you can do is create a workflow which send information, when the FILTER Field is changed to the state which is NOT in the Filter View Included.

Comment: I know it isn't actually deleted, that's why I said "is no longer shown". Guess I'll have to use workflows then, I was just hoping that there would be a less cumbersome solution..

Comment: No there is no other solution, create workflow for changing the filter property.

Answer (score 0):

We can easy achieve this using SharePoint designer workflow, the workflow design like the screenshot below.

[image]

If you don't want to use SharePoint designer workflow, we can also create a timer job, query the list items which Status are Completed, and send a email to users.

Refer to: [Send Email using Custom Timer Job in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1ce8ad/create-custom-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013-for-send-email/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't have access to SharePoint designer, nor can I create timer jobs